# Energy (glow) effect

Tags: rendering, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am having an issue with this render. I only want the circular energy in the image to glow, not the whole scene. It was working before i saved it. Then when i came back to the saved file and rendered, the whole scene glowed. Hopefully this is a simple fix.[image]

So managed to fix the issue only for a new one to arrive. I moved the circle to a different layer and turned off sky in RenderLayer001 in the layers tab. But now my human model glows with the circle..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the human model to a layer seperate from the glowing object and try rendering it that way.